# Install FTP Server with http read access without entering username nad password

Tags: ftp

I need a tutorial or something to install an FTP server on ubuntu and give write access to one user while also giving read access to http users. Basically I need to upload to the FTP server and have a directory listing of the files shared on that server over http and each file downloadable without a username and password for downloading. I have tried vsftpd and proftpd as well as gadmin-proftpd. Gadmin got me the closest but I am unable to create any new users. It lets me go through the motions of creating a user and when I click Apply no new user is created.I don't care what software I have to use I just need some clear instructions. I have followed more than a dozen tutorials and none have ended in the result I need.